# How do we barrel a variable number of params using `params object[] args` to another method?

Tags: c#, .net-core

No example from the [official docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Foo(params int[] args)
    {
        Bar(args) // error (I want to automatically pass args e.g.: Bar(args[0], args[1], args[2]...))
    }

    public static int Bar(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
        return a + b + c + d + e;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `Bar`? Unless it takes an `int[]` (with or without `params`) you'll need to do some sort of conversion/looping.

Comment: What does "barrel a variable" mean?

Comment: It has to work if `Bar` method can accomodate it as shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AUyYNl).

Comment: This code has minus 100 elegance points, you can't get it above 0.  Use a little helper struct or class to store constructor arguments.  Practical example is Process vs ProcessStartInfo in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below

```
public static void Foo(params int[] args)
        {
            Bar(args); // error (I want to automatically pass args e.g.: Bar(args[0], args[1], args[2]...))
        }
        public static int Bar(params int [] values)
        {
            int total = 0;
            foreach (int value in values)
            {
                total += value;
            }
            return total;
            //return a + b + c + d + e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));  //outputs 15
    }

    public static int Foo(params int[] args)
    {
        return (int)typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Bar), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, args.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray());
    }

    public static int Bar(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
    {
        return a + b + c + d + e;
    }
}
```